# Collision between ball and square

Tags: java, collision-detection

I am trying to get a ball to bounce off a square, but I am having trouble detecting the collision and having the ball bounce properly.I tried making two rectangles and using intersect, but this doesn't work and I don't know why. Should I write the collision detection manually? If so, how? Or is the rectangle method not working because of some other issue in my project. Here is my current collision detection.

```
    public boolean collidedWith(Ball ball){
            int ballX = ball.getXPosition();
            int ballY = ball.getYPosition();
            int ballRadius = ball.getRadius();
            int squareX = this.getXPosition();
            int squareY = this.getYPosition();

            Rectangle me = new Rectangle(squareX, squareY, size, size);
            Rectangle other = new Rectangle(ballX, ballY, ballRadius,ballRadius);

        if(me.intersects(other)|| other.intersects(me))
        {

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

  }
 }
```

Comment: What does `intersects()` do? If `me` intersects with `other` wouldn't `other` always intersect with `me`? What doesn't work? Can `Ball` really be considered a `Rectangle`?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us the problem you're having.  What is the observed behavior, and how does it differ from the behavior you want?

Comment: The ball hits the square and goes right through it instead of bouncing ( I have code that reverses the direction if a collision is detected)

Answer (score 0):

I find it very hard to understand your code. You didn't quite well.
But in order to detect a collision -
You check if the ball hit the bounds of the square.

```
    if (Math.abs(ballX + ballVelocityX) + ballRadius > SquareX)
 ...;
     if (Math.abs(ballY + ballVelocityY) + ballRadius > SquareY)
 ...;
```

Math abs is the absolute value.

Comment: If these are true does that mean there is a collision?